# Compact embedding and uniform convexity fo Sobolev space in Heisenberg group

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces, sobolev-spaces, heisenberg-group

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{H}$ is bounded domain where $\mathbb{H}$ is the Heisenberg group with homogeneous dimension $2N+2$. Then the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is defined as the space of all measurable functions $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $u,\nabla_{H}u\in L^p(\Omega)$ under the norm
$$
||u||=(||u||_{p}+||\nabla_{H}u||_{p}),
$$
where $||\cdot||_p$ denots the $L^p(\Omega)$ norm.

Then
(i) Is $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ uniformly convex for $p>1$?
(ii) Is the mapping $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\to L^p(\Omega)$ compact?

I do not get any counterexample neither some reference of the proof.

Can somebody kindly help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably $\Omega$ is _bounded_, and you have some boundary description...?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. $\Omega$ is smooth and bounded domain. I have added it in the question.

Comment: Oh, and now that I look, probably you wanted $p$-th powers inside the $p$-th root expression?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited it. Thanks. Do you have some ideas about the answer? I hope now the question is clear to you. Thanking you.

Comment: Google "Rellich-Kondrachev" theorem? It's not _exactly_ what you're asking... but is a true statement on more general domains in Riemannian manifolds. But/and some boundary conditions are needed on the behavior of the functions, or the Laplacian is not symmetric...

Comment: I will search, but what about the uniform convexinty?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm not much acquainted with "uniform convexity"...

Comment: Thank you very much. I googled it, but still not convinced whether the above embedding is compact or not.